# piping incoming http get request to outgoing write request on nodejs not working as expected

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a basic pub/sub event emitter and I'm having trouble understanding how I can pipe an incoming event with payload to all of the event's subscribers.  This is what I have:

```
app.post("/events", (req, res) => {
  const { type } = req.body;
  if (!type) {
    res.status(404).send(`no event found`);
    return;
  }
  if (!eventTypeToUrls[type]) {
    res.status(404).send(`no event ${type} subscribed to`);
    return;
  }
  let count = 0;
  const urls = eventTypeToUrls[type];
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    console.log("sending payload to >>", url);
    const writeStream = http.request(
      url + "/events",
      { method: "post" },
      () => {
        count += 1;
        if (count === urls.length) {
          res.status(201).send("ok");
        }
      }
    );
    writeStream.on("error", (e) => res.status(401).send(e));
    req.pipe(writeStream);
  });
});
```

I saw that I might in a non-piping setting would need to call `res.write` with the serialized payload, but since I'm piping from a readable stream to a writable stream, I'm not sure exactly how that would change.  I imagine I wouldn't need to call `res.end` either.  thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear - you want to send multiple http requests (with the request payload that was passed to `POST /events`)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the readable `req`-stream will already have been consumed, once the request-handler callback is hit, thus you cannot pipe it to a writeable stream.

However, if all you want to do is to send http-requests to all subscriber urls, you can use `Promise.all` to await the non-sequential processing of the requests and simply do `res.status(..).send(..)` once all promises are fulfilled. Something like this (I'm using superagent here as the http-request library):

```
app.post('/events', async (req, res) => {
  // ...
  try {
    await Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
      return superagent
        .post(url + '/events')
        .send(req.body);
    }));
    res.status(201).send("ok");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).end('something went wrong ...');
  }
});
```